# Is there any way to fixed the background image during the transition page? In jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, transition

I am making iphone app using jquery mobile.
I have two page which login and signup page.

Each page is different page and link with anchor

```
<div data-role="page" id="login">
<div data-role="content">
  <a href="signup.html">
 </div>
</div>
```

->signup.html

```
<div data-role="page" id="signup">
 <div data-role="content">
  <p>signup</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

when I click anchor the page change with transition.

!!!! But I don't want to change the background image during the transition
It means that only the content looks transitiong right to left.

Help me!

Answer (score 0):

you can try below line of code;

```
$(el).css({ 'background-color': 'white', 'background-repeat':'repeat'});
```

OR

```
$(el).css({ 'background-image': 'url('images/background.png')' , 'background-repeat':'repeat'});
```

i think this will good enough helpful to you.

Thanks.

Comment: is there any way with using some image files? like "background.png"

Comment: yes obviously..you can do by replacing **color** with **image**; See my edited answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to remove any background on the page and content area, set the background color or image on the **body** and then you should have sliding contents with fixed background. A persistent footer will also stay in place. Only drawback is the header, which will also slide in together with contents

Comment: i set background image on page using .ui-page
but when i set background-image on body it was hidden by page. How can  set background-image on body?